# NetCDF: nc-config not installed

Tags: macos, netcdf, fink

I've tried installing the NetCDF library using fink and manually. Either way, `nc-config` is not created. `ncdump` and the other utilities get installed to /sw/bin, but `nc-config` is nowhere to be found. (I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.2.) When I do the install manually and do `make check`, it runs through everything without throwing an error.

What could be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of netcdf are you installing?
I suggest you try using macports (https://www.macports.org/) for installing all those utilities on a OSx.

Answer (score 0):

nc-config is created from nc-config.in at configure time, then installed along with everything else.  So, let's look at your manual case:

- do you have a file called 'nc-config.in' in your source tree?
- after you run configure, do you have a file called nc-config?
- when do run "make install", what does the output say regarding nc-config?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that I didn't finish up by doing `make install`. Thanks for the help in walking me through it though!